# Fine Uploader get response before onComplete

Tags: fine-uploader

I am having problems with IE9 to get a json as response. In the service it returns a json but in the network in IE9 I see an XML. So, the responseJSON parameter in OnComplete comes without the response.

Is there any event before OnComplete? I want to parse the XML to json in the client side when it is IE9 or older.

I am using Fine-Uploader in basic mode.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

You will need to figure out how to return JSON from your server.  Fine Uploader expects a valid JSON response and this is non negotiable.  There is an open feature request that will allow integrators to contribute their own response parser, but this is a relatively low priority feature and it really doesn't apply to your situation.  Your best bet is to get control of your server and ensure the response is returned in the proper format.